# How do I delete a /System/Library kext in MacOS Monterey

Tags: monterey, kernel-extensions

I've tried

```
csrutil disable

csrutil authenticated-root disable

mount -uw /Volumes/MacintoshHD

cd /Volumes/<DiskName>/System/Library/Extensions

rm -rf rm /Path/IOAudioFamily.kext

rm -rf /System/Library/Caches/*
```

Which worked in previous versions, but these do not appear to work in Monterey

Comment: `/System/Library` can't be changed in Monterey, what are you trying to accomplish with the removal of a system kext?

Comment: @nohillside disabling a bluetooth device which is preventing another bluetooth device from being recognised.

Comment: Hmm, you might get better answers (or any at all) if your question asks about this (and not about a method which simply doesn't work anymore with sealed volumes).

Comment: Agree with @nohillside - what we have at the moment is known as an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @nohillside it's not possible for whatever reason is a canonical answer.